# iPhone CoreText: Find the pixel coordinates of a substring

Tags: iphone, ios4, substring, nsattributedstring, core-text

Here's a screenshot of the twitter app for reference: http://screencast.com/t/YmFmYmI4M

What I want to do is place a floating pop-over on top of a substring in an NSAttributedString that could span multiple lines.  NSAttributedString is a requirement for the project.

In the screenshot supplied, you can see that links are background-highlighted, so it leads me to believe that they're using CoreText and NSAttributedStrings. I also found something called CTRunRef ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTRunRef/Reference/reference.html ) which looks promising, but I'm having trouble fitting it all together conceptually.

In short, if I have a paragraph in core text and when I tap on a word, how do I find the bounding box for that word?

Answer (score 8):

Set some attribute in the attributed string that won't effect display, but will cause it to be laid out as a seperate glyph run, then use CoreText to layout the string

```
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
CTFrameRef ctframe = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), path, NULL);
```

Now you will have to hunt through the frame to find the relevant chunk of text.  Get the array of `CTLineRef`s with `CTFrameGetLines()`.

Iterate through the array, testing if the touch was on that line, by checking it is within the rect returned by `CTLineGetImageBounds()`.  If it is, now look through the glyph runs in the line.

Again, you can get an array of `CTRunRef`s with `CTLineGetGlyphRuns()`.  Check whether the tap was within the glyph run with `CTRunGetImageBounds()`, and if it was you can find the the range of indices in the original attributed string that the glyph run corresponds to with `CTRunGetStringIndices()`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to find Y  by CTLine and X by CTRun width and height you can get by word and font itself. ill attache my project link, its really simple code but you can reedit in order to meet your needs. hope it helps cheers if you improve general logic please let me know thx.
[textViewProject](http://creative.ge/xcode/textViewProject.zip)

Comment: Please don't ask in answers. Create a new question and link here.

Comment: vikingosegundo - this actually looks like a valid answer. Thanks for the link George!

Answer (score 2):

The link given by **George** was very helpful and got me what I wanted. But strange thing happened. It was working in **iOS SDK 4.0** but in the **iOS SDK 5** the position of the link appeared in wrong position on the view.

So I had to tweak the code a little bit. For the x coordinates of the touchable button, I had to use **CTRunGetTypographicBounds** instead of the **CTRunGetImageBounds** function.

So over all, in the tweaked code:
The y Coordinate , width and height was calculated using  **CTRunGetImageBounds**.
And x coordinate was calculated using **CTRunGetTypographicBounds**.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on a small library that does exactly that. You can find it here: https://github.com/pothibo/CMFramework

However, this library is in its alpha stage, there's optimization needed and some feature are lacking (line height is one of the urgent feature I want to add)

If you decide to use it and find issue, don't hesitate to post issues on github!